# How to check if all characters in a string are digits, and return true or false to main

Tags: c

I've created a function to check whether the characters in a string are digits, but when I run the program, and I for example give the input 2x, I don't get the error message I've created.

Here is the function where I check if a character is a digit

```
bool only_digits(string k)
{
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(k); i < len; i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(k[i]))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And here is the code in the main to print the result (if false)

```
if (only_digits(argv[1]) == false)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

I want arguments like 2x to be filtered as well. Right now, if I type only a or aaa, I get the error message, but when I start with a digit, I don't get the error message.

Comment: You're returning on the first iteration, so you're just testing the first character. Take `return true;` out of the loop. In the loop you return false if you find a non-digit. Then at the end of the loop you return true.